# How to cast custom post type into separate class instead of WP_Post

Tags: custom-post-types

I'd like to create a subclass of `WP_Post` and add some "model functionality" to it. How can i force WP to create objects of that child class instead of WP_Post itself, when i query for my custom post type?

**Example:**

Let's assume i have two custom post types: `Book` and `Review`. Each Book can have many Reviews. On my Book, I want a method to sum up all its reviews. I'd define the following class:

```
class Book extends WP_Post
{
    public function reviewsSummary()
    {
        // Retrieve all reviews for $this book
        // Sum up their ratings
        // Return that sum
    }
}
```

Is there a way, for example when calling `register_post_type()`, to force WordPress into casting all posts of type "book" into my `Book` class instead of `WP_Post`?

Could look something like this:

```
register_post_type('book', [
    …,
    'class' => Acme\Models\Book::class
]);
```

Comment: I like the idea of asking register_post_type to return you own class instead of the wp_post class. But no that functionality does not exist in the current class.

Comment: You might want to use a _Decorator_ if you need to extend the functionality or a _Proxy_ if you need to get an layer of abstraction for refactoring and decoupling (not for gaining access to private or protected functions!). You could as well build a factory and some repository where you can return whatever pleases your needs. `WP_Post` is rarely needed directly in cases where you do not have to rely on checks against a concrete type.

Comment: Btw people with similar questions might be interested in Timber: http://timber.github.io/timber/

Answer (score 10):

`WP_Post` class in WP is `final`, so it explicitly forbids subclassing. It is also quite vague in practice, a lot of code around will happily take/produce post–*like* objects as long as they have established data structure.

It is challenging to recommend an alternative without knowing more about your specific needs. In a general and assuming use in templates the typical would be to create a template tag function that will calculate score for review post, provided to it as argument and/or current in the Loop.

Comment: It won't be final for too much longer we hope: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24672#comment:13

Comment: True, had to learn it the hard way… :(

Answer (score 5):

### How to "subclass" `WP_Post`

Thank you, @Rarst for pointing out the issue that **you can't subclass WP_Post**, which is a major problem in this case.

#### Workaround

There is, however, a way of working around it using a wrapper class that has a real WP_Post object stored as an attribute and exposes it via magic methods in order to behave like one.

Two examples of that approach can be found [here](https://github.com/hanamura/wp-model) and [here](https://danielmenjivar.com/blog/extending-the-wp_post-class).

*Warning: In many cases, this approach might not work for different reasons, one being that these objects won't pass an `instanceof WP_Post` check.*

---

### Where to hook in

So let's assume we could replace WP_Post somehow. The thing i was actually looking for was **where to hook in** in order to replace `WP_Post`. The answer to this question is the `posts_results` filter and was given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40631962/3919281